# Informix Select and output result as a matrix

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table called "sales_pos" with following columns:

```
cust_nr ; cust_name ; cust_ans ; date ; month_year ; value_goods
```

Example:

```
1234;Jon Doe;New York;31/01/2015;1/2015;250,00
4711;Max Muster;New York;22/03/2015;01/2015;900,00
0812;Will Smith;New York;22/02/2015;01/2015;300,00
1234;Jon Doe;New York;11/01/2015;1/2015;150,00
```

I want a selec with a result as follows:

```
Customer                 |1/2015|2/2015|3/2015|4/2015| .. |12/2015|
0812 Will Smith New York |300,00|..    |..    |..    | .. |..     | 
1234 Jon Doe New York    |400,00|..    |..    |..    | .. |..     |  
4711 Max Muster New York |..    |..    |900,00|..
```

..

```
Select 
  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans, month_year, sum(value_goods)
from sales_pos
group by 
  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans, month_year
```

This select-statement has all information i need but I don't know how to transform this result into the matrix above.

I also tried:

```
select
  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans, month_year, sum(value_goods)
from sales_pos
where
  month_year = '1/2015'
group by cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans
UNION ALL
select
  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans, month_year, sum(value_goods)
from sales_pos
where
  month_year = '2/2015'
group by cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans
UNION ALL
select
  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans, month_year, sum(value_goods)
from sales_pos
where
  month_year = '3/2015'
group by cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans
UNION ALL
...
```

But this did not work either.
I hope somebody can help. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a working solution for informix 7.5

```
select DISTINCT 
   CUST.cust_nr, CUST.cust_name, CUST.cust_ans, 
   (select sum(M01.value_goods) from $table as M01 where M01.month_year = '1/2015' and M01.cust_nr = CUST.cust_nr),
   (select sum(M02.value_goods) from $table as M02 where M02.month_year = '2/2015' and M02.cust_nr = CUST.cust_nr),
   ...
   (select sum(M12.value_goods) from $table as M12 where M12.month_year = '12/2015' and M12.cust_nr = CUST.cust_nr)
from sales_pos as CUST order by CUST.cust_nr;
```

I don't like this solution, but at least it works :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the headers are, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
Select cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans,
       sum(case when month_year = '1/2015' then value_goods end) as MY_012015,
       sum(case when month_year = '2/2015' then value_goods end) as MY_022015,
       . . .
       sum(case when month_year = '12/2015' then value_goods end) as MY_122015
from sales_pos
group by  cust_nr, cust_name, cust_ans;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is informix sql syntax? I get a syntax error.

Comment: The syntax is OK (tested under 11.70). What version of Informix are you using? Very old versions may not support `CASE`. For what it's worth the query could be shortened by using `SUM(DECODE(month_year,'1/2015',value_goods)) AS MY_012015` but if your server doesn't support `CASE`, it won't support `DECODE` either.

Comment: You are right. My version is 7.5 it is very old :-) Unfortunately I have no choice. How could I solve my problem without using CASE and DECODE